# How to use a lambda with Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I was able to solve this, but wondering why `lambda` doesn't work.

I am trying to replace spaces in column names with underscore:

```
df.columns = df.columns.apply(lambda x: replaceable(' ','_'))
```

Why doesn't this work?

However, with the below I got it to work:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ','_')
```

Why I can't apply `lambda` and how I could apply it?

Comment: There is no `.apply` method for `pandas.indexes.base.Index` objects.

Comment: `df.columns = [str(x).replace(' ', '_') for x in df.columns]` would give you something similar to the lambda syntax.

Comment: In general do you know on what the apply method could be used.I understand do.cols doesnt have that method. Is there a way of intutively knowing (or hard rule) on what the apply,lambda combo can be used

Comment: Sure, you can read the documentation :).  `.apply` can only be used on [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) objects.

Comment: I always check the [API documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JAV has already said in the comment - `df.columns` doesn't have method `.apply()`:

```
In [307]: df.columns.apply(lambda x: print(x))
...
skipped
...
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

AFAIK the most idiomatic solution is either yours:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ','_')
```

or

```
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_'))
```

Comment: In general do you know on what the apply method could be used.I understand do.cols doesnt have that method. Is there a way of intutively knowing (or hard rule) on what the apply,lambda combo can be used – Kris just now   edit

Comment: @Kris, usually i'm using [ipython](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/tutorial.html) or [Jupyter](https://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/what_is_jupyter.html). Using them you can type for instance `df.columns.` and press `TAB` - it'll show us all available methods and attributes - it's  IMO the fastest and the most convinient way to see available methods...

Comment: Sure , i do the same thing only problem is it doesnt show you if its an attribute or a function. Now that aside , i ran into a new but similar issue. Say i want to ignore all the NaN values . So tried this, but doesnt work do you see why , it doesnt give me an error too (also tried using pd.np.nan) ->                            
               df = df.applymap(lambda x: x != 'NaN')

Comment: Another issue with intellisense in Jupy Notebook - Lets say , i want to do   
          df.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending = False)  , after .sum() it doesnt show my any options, all i get is .ipynb_checkpoints , R data , R history . Do you face same issue . Also in Spyder nothing shows up at all even for df. .

Comment: @Kris, it doesn't show you options because Jypiter doesn't know what kind of object will be returned...